# Is py-datatable compatible with Dask?

Tags: dask, py-datatable

Does Python Datatable work with distributed big data frameworks like Dask?

I have plenty of `data.table` experience on `R`, but not on Python. For a person familiar with the tools this might sound a stupid question, apologies for that.

Comment: I'm not familiar with datatable, but from poking around their website, my guess would be no. generally, you don't want to mix dask with other things which explicitly manage threads and processes. why not just use [`dask.dataframe`](https://docs.dask.org/en/stable/dataframe.html)?

Comment: Thank you. That is my _guess_ too. The reason being interested is `datatable`'s performance. At least the `R` version is pretty much fastest single-computer "dataframe" format. I have `R` `data.table` based pipeline and I am looking to move to a Python-based platform for more robust behavior.

Comment: py-datatable is not compatible with dask AFAIK. dask has excellent support for pandas though. is the computation you are running with pydatatable inefficient?

Comment: I am planning to migrate the codebase from `R` to Python and looking for the right tools. `R`'s `data.table` is really fast, therefore I got interested about `pydatatable` in the first place. 

But I am at the limits of single machine performance (RAM) at the moment. `pydatatable` claims to support out-of-mem calculations, but I could not find anything in the docs. Dask seems to be a far more scalable framework, so I think it is better to go with what it provides out of the box. I am not sure does it have its own "pandas" / "Numpy" data frame implementations or use those natively.

Comment: I ended up using Apache Arrow's dataset as out-of-memory data format. I chose Parquet as file format although Arrow's native format might be bit faster to read. I kept the processing pipeline in `R` `data.table` for a moment since refactoring all the code is a massive undertaking. `data.table` has extremely powerful API. So I am still stuck with single computer processing, but the memory limit has been pushed bit further. No Dask this time.